# how to disable buttons based on a condition in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp, button

how can I disable a button by checking a condition in my jsp? If true,then the button is enabled,if false,then the button is disabled. The condition would be checking the value of a variable. I know how to disable a button using javascript, but to use it along with the condition in jsp is what I'm not able to figure out. Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using JSTL construction like this:

```
<input type="button" <c:if test="${variable == false}"><c:out value="disabled='disabled'"/></c:if>">
```

For more examples see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211/index.html

Comment: No need to compare with false. Just use ${!variable}. And no need to use c:out for static text that doesn't need HTML escaping.

Comment: Maybe this changed since 2015 but for me it complains just before `<c:if` with `Tag start is not closed`, for `input` I guess. But also it seems syntax is not good, or you made a typo since I don't know what the `"` before last `>` is doing, that makes an odd number or `"` then last has no one matching it, didn't you mean to put a `/` instead ?

Answer (score 11):

Or simply you could do it using `el` directly like this:

```
<input type="button" ${ condition ? 'disabled="disabled"' : ''}/>
```

As an example:

```
<input type="button" ${ someVariable eq 5  ? 'disabled="disabled"' : ''}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be something like this:

```
 <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${condition == true}">
      <input type="button" disabled="disabled"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <input type="button" />
    </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Spring's form tag](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-view-jsp-tags) library, you could also write:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<form:form>
 ...
 <form:button type="button" disabled="${condition}">Name of button</form:button>
</form:form>
```