# How to change the label of button after you login

Tags: javascript, java, button

I'm working on a school project in Java. I'm able to login user successfully who registered. But when he/she loged-in how can I hide Login and Register page link and replace them with MyAlumni. And after sign-out how can I show them again.
Here is the coding of my links on MasterPage

```
 <td id="menucontainer" align="center">
                    <br>
<button id="homeBtn" onclick="window.location.href='Main.do'"></button>
<br>
<button id="loginBtn" onclick="window.location.href='ForwardGeneralAction.do?page=Login'"></button>
<br>
<button id="signupBtn" onclick="window.location.href='ForwardGeneralAction.do?page=SignUp'"></button>
<br>
<button id="helpBtn" onclick="window.location.href='ForwardGeneralAction.do?page=Help'"></button>
<br>
<button id="contactBtn" onclick="window.location.href='ForwardGeneralAction.do?page=Contact'"></button>
<br>
```

Please explain me step by step what I have to do. Many thanks

Comment: in Java is the project, but this menu is Javascript

Comment: This post shows two techniques for hiding buttons based on a condition, in java. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6633059/16391

Comment: @MikeThunder if my answer helped (which i think it should!) can you throw me an accept? I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, site will have a `login.master` to handle the login stuff, and like a `site.master` or `default.master` to handle the rest of it. I would suggest this in your case, too. You'd just put the login/register menu in login.master, and then the other menu in site.master.

In response to your comment, wherever your current master page is, add another one (right click, add, new item, master page) and copy the header type stuff from your other master page (sorry, I haven't done any web dev in java so I don't know the exact syntax)

And then your login master page (at least the menu part of it) will look like this:

```
<td id="menucontainer" align="center">
                    <br>
<button id="homeBtn" onclick="window.location.href='Main.do'"></button>
<br>
<button id="loginBtn" onclick="window.location.href='ForwardGeneralAction.do?page=Login'"></button>
<br>
<button id="signupBtn" onclick="window.location.href='ForwardGeneralAction.do?page=SignUp'"></button>
```

and then your other master page (the menu part) will look like this:

```
<td id="menucontainer" align="center">
                    <br>
<button id="homeBtn" onclick="window.location.href='Main.do'"></button>
<br>
<button id="alumniBtn" onclick="window.location.href='MyAlumni.do'"></button>
<button id="helpBtn" onclick="window.location.href='ForwardGeneralAction.do?page=Help'"></button>
<br>
<button id="contactBtn" onclick="window.location.href='ForwardGeneralAction.do?page=Contact'"></button>
```

The rest of the master page stuff is up to you!

Comment: can you give an example how to do it. Im a beginer. Thanks in advance