# Enable/Disable image button in JSP page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I have a JSP page where there's an **image button**, which is `enabled` by default. My requirement is to `disable` the said image button when the page loads.

Below is the snippet of the code which renders the image button, and it is enabled, that is, on clicking it redirects to another page.

Please help me modify the code so that this would be disabled on load, until enabled again from code.

```
<td class='cls_valign_top' colspan="2">
 <mortgage:linkTag event="initMandateCreate" statusText="create an mortgage">
   <img src="images/<mortgage:imageDir/>/<mortgage:imagePrefix/>mort‌​gage.gif" width="155" height="39" alt="create mortgage" border="0">
 </mortgage:linkTag>
</td>
```

Comment: You can add disabled attribute to your button tag to make it disabled by default. Then programatically you can remove this attribute to make it enabled.

Comment: Here goes the complete line of code <td class='cls_valign_top' colspan="2"><mortgage:linkTag event="initMandateCreate" statusText="create an mortgage"><img src="images/<mortgage:imageDir/>/<mortgage:imagePrefix/>mortgage.gif" width="155" height="39" alt="create mortgage" border="0"></mortgage:linkTag></td>

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633059/how-to-disable-buttons-based-on-a-condition-in-jsp

Comment: @Fr333du But the link says change in mode based on Condition. I am looking for default disable of button image. Can you please modify the above code and let me know how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see, here is a solution:
http://jqueryutils.blogspot.com/2013/01/custom-disabled-attribute-in-html.html

Comment: Tried with approach, But it's not working in my case.