# Disable button onclick after user clicks it once

Tags: javascript, xml, jsp

I have two files..one .jspx and other .js page.
Code of .jspx file:

```
<form name="vacNotificationEdit" method="post" >
    <input type="button" class="button_medium" name="Save As Draft"  id="Save"   value="Save As Draft"     onclick="javascript:vacFunction('save');" ><![CDATA[&nbsp; ]]></input> 
    <input type="submit" class="button_big"  name="Submit for Review" id="Submit" value="Submit for Review" onclick="javascript:vacFunction('submit');" ></input>
</form>
```

code of .js page:

```
function vacFunction(strAction)
{
    if(deptMgrId!=""){
        document.vacNotificationEdit.hidAction.value = strAction;
        document.vacNotificationEdit.action ="vacationNotification";
        document.vacNotificationEdit.submit();
    }
}
```

I need to disable the submit button after it is clicked once.Please help me through this.I am stuck.I have used disabled=true/false but no luck .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to disable buttons based on a condition in jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633059/how-to-disable-buttons-based-on-a-condition-in-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

You should first submit your form and then change the value of your submit:

Here is working example: https://output.jsbin.com/mobogoguxe

https://jsbin.com/mobogoguxe/edit?html

Disable `submit` button with form submit:

```
onClick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending…'; "
```

Only Disable `submit` button:

```
onClick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending…'; "
```

### Example:

Demo here: https://jsbin.com/xakata/8/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ar">
<head>
<meta charset=utf8>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function vacFunction(btnAction)
    {
        if(btnAction.id == 'Submit'){
            //if clicked on 'Submit for Review' button
            btnAction.disabled = true;
            console.log("Submit for Review");
        }
        if(btnAction.id == 'Save'){
            //if clicked on 'Save As Draft' button
            btnAction.disabled = true;
            console.log("Save As Draft");
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="vacNotificationEdit" method="post" >
    <input type="button" class="button_medium" name="Save As Draft"  id="Save"   value="Save As Draft" onClick="return vacFunction(this);" ><![CDATA[&nbsp; ]]></input> 
    <input type="submit" class="button_big"  name="Submit for Review" id="Submit" value="Submit for Review" onClick="return vacFunction(this);"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer.But i had a doubt that the example you have given in your link is for both the buttons but i want it only for submit button.. and is it necessary to give a this.value='Sending....' because after submitting it is redirected to other page of the application and when i ran the given link example,the button is not disabled.Also I need to use the onclick function onclick="javascript:vacFunction('submit'); that I am using because validations are present in this function.