# How to disable a button permanently - Even after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to disable the button ***for every user*** once clicked, but it is getting enabled when I refresh the page.

```
<td>   
<form action="runNotifications" method="post">
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled='disabled'" name="RunNotifications" value="Run Notifications">
</form>
```

Is there any way I can disable the button permanently for every user once it has been clicked?

Comment: just use disabled="disabled" attribute on input

Comment: @MohsenZia I got the impression that they want to disable it after it's been clicked one time. So the can't just hardcode it as disabled.

Comment: Use your localStorage, a file or a database to store the information permanently.

Comment: @MohsenZia Have used the same in above code, but the button gets enables once the page is refreshed

Comment: set a flag in your database, when click function set the flag  and on page load check the flag from database and write style.

Comment: So use cookie or memcached or db or ... you should use ajax.

Comment: Use Database or cookie or browser storage(Local storage)

Comment: @MohsenZia I am very new to html/javascript, a related code snippet would be helpful, please.

Comment: Judging from your comments you can ONLY EVER do that from the server - best is to not even send it to the user if the server says someone clicked the button before. The second best is to ajax the disabled state, but why not just use the server?

Comment: @mplungjan Doesn't seems duplicate to me. Obviously, I googled before asking the question but I didn't got any satisfying answer tats the reason I posted the question. The link shared does not specify how to disable the button permanently.

Comment: Sure looks like a duplicate to me. You need to store the button state on the server and then disable it or not show it depending on the state of the button, so either `<input type="button" ${ condition ? 'disabled="disabled"' : ''}/>` or https://stackoverflow.com/a/6638260/295783

Comment: @mplungjan I am very new to the technology, I do not understand anything from the below <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${condition == true}">
      <input type="button" disabled="disabled"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <input type="button" />
    </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>

Comment: @mplungjan Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166674/discussion-between-prats-and-mplungjan).

Answer (score 0):

Use a cookie to store the state of the button and check its value when your page loads. If the cookie doesn't exist, you button is clickable, else you can add the disabled property to your button.

Comment: Okay, but the button should get disabled for all the users who login to the website. If stored in cache, I guess it will get disabled for the user who has taken the action and will not be disabled globally

Comment: Any suggestions, on how to set it disabled globally for every user who logs in the site?

Comment: @Prats save the state of the button in a database.

Comment: @FLeX I am very new to html/javascript, a related code snippet would be helpful please.

Comment: @Prats ah, what you need to understand is that HTML/JavaScript is client-side. Anytime you need to save a state that should consistent for every user you would have to use something like a database. It's hard to provide a snippet, but maybe somebody else can explain this better than I can.

Comment: You didn't clarify that this button should be disabled for everyone. As @FLeX mentioned, you should store the state of the button in a database then.

Answer (score 0):

All static data such as JavaScript and HTML or CSS, are cleared after refreshing the browser.

If you want to save data even after refreshing, use localStorage ability of the browser.

This way you will save the data even after refreshing until you clear the browser's Cache.

```
<form action="runNotifications" method="post">

<input type="submit" onclick="localStorage.buttonDisabled='disabled';this.disabled=localStorage.buttonDisabled" name="RunNotifications" value="Run Notifications">

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't works when another user logs in from another browser.

Comment: @Prats then you can ONLY do it via the server.

Comment: @Prats , as mentioned above, if you want to share this data among other users, then you have to save the button's attribute in the DataBase